# Access to Linux Host VirtualBox Shared Folder from Linux Guest with anyone user

Tags: centos, virtualbox, shared-folders

I was reading multiple answer in order to access from guest to host on Linux, and I found two methods.

But, they are not working for me.

I using `VirtualBox` `Version 6.1.12 r139181 (Qt5.12.5)`

```
$ uname -r
5.7.8-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
$
```

Now, from the Guest

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$

$ uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic
$
```

Location

```
$ pwd
/home/anita
$

anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ ll
total 112
drwxr-xr-x 19 anita anita  4096 jul 29 19:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root   4096 jul 23 00:10 ../
-rw-------  1 anita anita  5909 jul 31 09:15 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 anita anita   220 jul 23 00:10 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 anita anita  3771 jul 23 00:10 .bashrc
drwx------ 15 anita anita  4096 jul 27 00:33 .cache/
drwxr-xr-x 14 anita anita  4096 jul 26 14:22 .config/
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x  3 anita anita  4096 jul 28 00:05 Documents/
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Downloads/
drwx------  3 anita anita  4096 jul 28 00:00 .gnupg/
drwxrwx---  1 root  vboxsf 4096 jul 31 08:34 host/
drwxrwxr-x  4 anita anita  4096 jul 29 12:04 .kube/
drwxr-xr-x  3 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 .local/
drwx------  5 anita anita  4096 jul 23 23:03 .mozilla/
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Music/
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Pictures/
-rw-r--r--  1 anita anita   807 jul 23 00:10 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Public/
drwxr-xr-x  3 anita anita  4096 jul 23 21:57 snap/
drwx------  2 anita anita  4096 jul 26 14:20 .ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 anita anita     0 jul 23 22:03 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Templates/
-rw-r-----  1 anita anita     5 jul 29 19:57 .vboxclient-clipboard.pid
-rw-r-----  1 anita anita     5 jul 29 19:57 .vboxclient-display-svga-x11.pid
-rw-r-----  1 anita anita     5 jul 29 19:57 .vboxclient-draganddrop.pid
-rw-r-----  1 anita anita     5 jul 29 19:57 .vboxclient-seamless.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 anita anita  4096 jul 23 00:34 Videos/
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

using `usermod`

```
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $USER
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

using `adduser`

```
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
The user `anita' is already a member of `vboxsf'.
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

The test in order to access (for read/write)

```
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ cd host/
bash: cd: host/: Permission denied
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$
```

instead of root.

```
anita@ubuntu--k8s-master:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for anita: 
root@ubuntu--k8s-master:~# ls -l /home/anita/host/
total 69032
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul 21 06:02  bin
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  5 20:30  Desktop
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul 23 00:00  Develops
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 ago  1 10:31  Documents
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 ago  1 10:12  Downloads
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 58477923 jul 21 07:26  minikube
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  5 20:30  Music
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul 23 01:03  Pictures
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  7 19:16  Programs
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  5 20:30  Public
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 ago  1 10:55  snap
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  5 20:30  Templates
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  1764044 jul  6 01:03  test.wav
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     1905 jul  6 02:50  text
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul  6 05:40  Videos
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     4096 jul 25 21:08 'VirtualBox VMs'
root@ubuntu--k8s-master:~#
```

**What happens?**

**How I can solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

by looking at the sequence of the commands you have provided you should be able to access your `~/host` mounted directory.

I assume you need to logout + login from the current `shell` for it to re-read your groups and enable you to access the group permissions. Either open a new terminal window / tab or logout / login from X-window manager to be able to use GUI applications when accessing the `~/host` folder.